# Is it possible to run the asyncio.Server instance while the event loop is already running

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand, is it possible to run the `asyncio.Server` instance while the event loop is already running by `run_forever` method (from a separate thread, of course). 
As I understand, the server can be started either by `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.start_server(...))` or by 
`await asyncio.start_server(...)`, if the loop is already running. 
The first way is not acceptable for me, since the loop is already running by run_forever method. But I also can't use the await expression, since I'm going to start it from outside the "loop area" (e.g. from the main method, which can't be marked as async, right?)

```
def loop_thread(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
        print("loop clesed")

class SchedulerTestManager:
    def __init__(self): 
        ...

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.servers_loop_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=loop_thread, args=(self.loop, ))
         ...

    def start_test(self):
        self.servers_loop_thread.start()
        return self.servers_loop_thread

    def add_router(self, router):
        r = self.endpoint.add_router(router)
        host = router.ConnectionParameters.Host
        port = router.ConnectionParameters.Port
        srv = TcpServer(host, port)
        server_coro = asyncio.start_server(
            self.handle_connection, self.host, self.port)
        # does not work since add_router is not async
        # self.server = await server_coro
        # does not work, since the loop is already running
        # self.server = self.loop.run_until_complete(server_coro)
        return r


def maind():
   st_manager = SchedulerTestManager()
   thread = st_manager.start_test()
   router = st_manager.add_router(router)
```

Of cource, the simplest solution is to add all routers (servers) before starting the test (running the loop). But I want try to implement it, so it would be possible to add a router when a test is already running. I thought the `loop.call_soon` (`call_soon_threadsafe`) methods can help me, but it seems the can't shedule a coroutine, but just a simple function.

Hope that my explanation is not very confusing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communicating between event loop executed in one thread and conventional old good threaded code executed in other thread you might use [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus) library.

It's a queue with two interfaces: async and thread-safe sync one.

This is usage example:

```
import asyncio
import janus

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = janus.Queue(loop=loop)

def threaded(sync_q):
    for i in range(100):
        sync_q.put(i)
    sync_q.join()

@asyncio.coroutine
def async_coro(async_q):
    for i in range(100):
        val = yield from async_q.get()
        assert val == i
        async_q.task_done()

fut = loop.run_in_executor(None, threaded, queue.sync_q)
loop.run_until_complete(async_coro(queue.async_q))
loop.run_until_complete(fut)
```

You may create a task waiting new messages from the queue in a loop and starting new servers on request. Other thread may push new message into the queue asking for a new server.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that's what I'm looking for.